# Circular Linked List in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm new to java and I am working on an assignment with a linked list. I was given a tester class and I am only to insert my code in specific locations in the linked list class. To begin with, the problem I face is I'm not able to print my list and see if my code is working or if I am making any progress. The tester file uses "printList(nameOftheList)" but doesn't print any elements of the list. I tried using System.outprintln(nameOftheList) to test, but I get what I believe is the location of the list and not the elements on the list. I been working on this program for a couple days now and I understand linked lists, but my book only covers so much and I haven't been able to apply anything of what I have found in the web.

If someone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Here the given tester:

tester:

```
public class AddTester
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
      LinkedList names = new LinkedList();

      names.addFirst("Tom");
      names.addFirst("Harry");
      names.addFirst("Dick");

      names.add("Romeo");
      printList(names);
      System.out.println("Expected: Dick Harry Tom Romeo");
      ....
```

Here is the class I'm working on:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
A circular linked list.
 */
public class LinkedList
{  
    private Node last;
    // Don't add other instance fields

/** 
Constructs an empty linked list.
 */
public LinkedList()
{  
    last = null;
}

/**
Returns the first element in the linked list.
@return the first element in the linked list
 */
public Object getFirst()
{  
    //. . .
    if (last == null) 
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return last.data;
}

/**
Removes the first element in the linked list.
@return the removed element
 */
public Object removeFirst()
{  
    //. . .
    if (last == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object element = last.data;
    last = last.next;
    return element;
}

/**
Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
@param element the element to add
 */
public void addFirst(Object element)
{  
    //. . .
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = element;
    newNode.next = last;
    last = newNode;
}

/**
Adds an element to the end of the linked list.
@param element the element to add
 */
public void add(Object element)
{  
    //. . .
    if (last == null)
    {
        addFirst(element);
        //position = last;
    }
    else
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = last.next;
        last.next = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }
    last = last;
}

/**
Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
@return an iterator for iterating through this list
 */
public ListIterator listIterator()
{  
    return new LinkedListIterator();
}

private class Node
{  
    public Object data;
    public Node next;
}

private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
{              
    private Node position;
    private Node previous;

    /**
    Constructs an iterator that points to the front
    of the linked list.
     */
    public LinkedListIterator()
    {  
        position = null;
        previous = null;
    }

    /**
    Moves the iterator past the next element.
    @return the traversed element
     */
    public Object next()
    {  
        //. . .
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        previous = position; //rmbr for remove

        if (position == null)
            position = last;
        else
            position = position.next;

        return position.data;

    }

    /**
    Tests if there is an element after the iterator 
    position.
    @return true if there is an element after the iterator 
    position
     */
    public boolean hasNext()
    {  
        //. . .
        if (position != null)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    /**
    Adds an element before the iterator position
    and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
    @param element the element to add
     */
    public void add(Object element)
    {  
        //. . .
        if (position == null)
        {
            addFirst(element);
            position = last;
        }
    }

    /**
    Removes the last traversed element. This method may
    only be called after a call to the next() method.
     */
    public void remove()
    {  
        //. . .
        if (previous == position)
           throw new IllegalStateException();
         if (position == last)
        {
            removeFirst();
        }
         else
         {
             previous.next = position.next;
        }
        position = previous;
    }

    /**
    Sets the last traversed element to a different 
    value. 
    @param element the element to set
     */
    public void set(Object element)
    {
        if (position == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        position.data = element;
    }

}
```

}

This is the iterrator:

```
public interface ListIterator
{  
   /**
      Moves the iterator past the next element.
      @return the traversed element
   */
   Object next();

   /**
      Tests if there is an element after the iterator 
      position.
      @return true if there is an element after the iterator 
      position
   */
   boolean hasNext();

   /**
      Adds an element before the iterator position
      and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
      @param element the element to add
   */
   void add(Object element);

   /**
      Removes the last traversed element. This method may
      only be called after a call to the next() method.
   */
   void remove();

   /**
      Sets the last traversed element to a different 
      value. 
      @param element the element to set
   */
   void set(Object element);
}
```

Comment: Read up on the `toString()` method of the `Object` class which all classes inherit from.

Comment: use the iterator to print each node data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Iterator or your LinkedList :

```
    static String printList(LinkedList names){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Expected : ");
            ListIterator st = names.listIterator();

            while(st.hasNext()){
                //Here implements stuff to get the element of your linkedList and add 
               //it to the StringBuilder
            }
            return sb.toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for `LinkedListIterator`, you set the field `position` to `null` and (unless I'm missing something) this never changes.

Then, in `hasNext()`, you check if `position == null` and return false if that is the case.

This means that, if `printList` is using your `LinkedListIterator`, it is probably checking `hasNext()` to figure out when to stop printing. Since your `hasNext()` always returns false, `printList` can only assume it is looking at an empty list.